# Does Vitamin C in Indian Gooseberry have skincare benefits when applied directly to skin, or when eaten?

Tags: nutrition, natural-remedies, vitamins, dermatology, fruit

There are several health product sites making claims about Vitamin C and Indian Gooseberry.  They say it helps with skin problems.

Note that "Amla" is one of the names for Indian Gooseberry.

For example:

- [Paula's Choice (store) says Vitamin C can](http://www.paulaschoice.com/expert-advice/anti-aging/_/how-does-vitamin-c-help-skin#antiaging):

  > Reduce the appearance of brown spots and other types of sun damage
  > Helps boost healthy collagen production (hello, firmer skin!)
  > Reduce inflammation and irritation, both of which cause a cascade of damage
  > Fade post-breakout red marks by improving skin’s natural healing response
- This [health advice site claims](http://www.onlymyhealth.com/benefits-of-amla-juice-for-skin-1405075388):

  > You could keep your look youthful for long by drinking amla juice.
  > Again the hero here is vitamin C which is found in abundance in amla
  > juice. Regular intake of amla juice delays the effects of premature
  > ageing such as fine lines and wrinkles, and dark spots.

[A beauty website](http://www.beautyglimpse.com/incredible-benefits-amla-juice-skin-hair/) has claimed that on its application to skin it has the following benefits:

> Amla juice can also help treat pigmentation like all other fruits rich in
> Vitamin C. ***Apply some amla juice on your face as a face pack and leave it
> to dry. Wash off with cold water. This helps you get rid of tanning
> and blemishes in your skin.***
>
> ***Using amla juice as a face pack or drinking it regularly helps in toning
> your skin and keeping it firm due to its anti-aging properties.***

---

So, is it true that Indian Gooseberry, **applied to my face in liquid or powder form, and/or when eaten** can have the positive effects claimed?

Answer (score 1):

Emblica officinalis (of the family Euphorbiaceae) also known as Indian gooseberry in the form of fruits contain mostly carbohydrate with moderate fiber content and are [rich](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23601399) in vitamin C, with some other unique bioactives. Emblica officinalis extract is Generally Recognized As Safe as a food additive by [FDA](http://www.fda.gov/Food/IngredientsPackagingLabeling/GRAS/NoticeInventory/ucm400705.htm).

The effects listed below were noted in uncontrolled or observational studies only and more research is [needed](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-784-indian%20gooseberry.aspx?activeingredientid=784&activeingredientname=indian%20gooseberry) for conclusion of evidence of the [effects](http://globalresearchonline.net/journalcontents/v24-2/25.pdf).

Hair

Application of the Emblica officinalis fruit extract in solution to [mice](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22178180) was found to increase hair follicle count and was second best to ethanolic extract of Carthamus tinctorius from safflower.

Skin

Emblica officinalis appears to be capable of protecting skin cells from UV radiation by reducing the increase in reactive oxygen species which is researched [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21443845) and [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20688142).